# How Can I Give Users Permission to Send Email from a Distribution List?

Tags: exchange-2010

Basically what I'm trying to do is this:

We've developed a website which will send out an email (using smtp) as xyz@domain.com. When somebody replies to an email from the address it actually goes to a distribution list configured in Exchange 2010.

I'd then like for the people on that distro to be able to reply to the email as the distribution list rather than as their personal email address.

Can somebody tell me how to go about setting this up in Exchange 2010? Is there a better method to do this (perhaps creating the distro as a user and then having their email forwarded to a distro and granting people permission to send as?)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reply as a distribution group. You just need to make the modifications in Active Directory or in powershell instead of the EMC.

Add the `Send-As` permission to the distribution group for the distribution group. That way all members of the DG can send mail as that address. (note this can take up to 3 hours to filter through all the cached permissions in exchange)

**Note** If you send to an internal user as the distribution group it will appear as the actual user that sent it. So make sure you verify by sending it to an external address.

Here is some sample powershell code (this requires importing the active directory module):

> Add-ADPermission -Identity GroupName -user GroupName -ExtendedRights "Send-as"

Comment: Sometimes even **longer** than three hours. There is a value that you can change in the registry to lower it down if you make a lot of changes though.

Comment: Shouldn't that read '-user Username' and not '-user groupname'?

Comment: No, remember you are giving rights to the group to send, not a specific user. The logic seems a bit off until you wrap your head around it.

Answer (score 1):

Create a user account (for example: dl1@domain.com) for that email address, configure forwarding from this account to the DL that will contain all the required recipients (could be a dl1-dl@domnain.com for example. Assign the "send as" permission on dl1@domain.com to the required users. In addition, configure dl1-dl@domain.com to accept emails only from dl1@domain.com and hide it from the OAB.
Adjust the dl1-dl@domain.com members as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Exchange 2010 moved most of its commands into powershell including this one. The command is below.

```
Set-DistributionGroup GroupName -GrantSendOnBehalfTo UserName
```

Wait 5 and then test.

Comment: That is not the same thing as sending **as** the group. When you read the message it will say something like "Joe Schmoe on behalf of Group Name".